# SQL super keys and commands

Tags: sql, database-schema

[Relation Schema for Questions Revision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtmQd.png)

I have a question Im doing for revision, Identify two Superkeys and a candidate key in the account_branch relation. I have an idea but I need verification if anyone has suggestions, so far I have candidate key being account_number, super keys being Account_number + branch_name and also account_number + assets

Another SQL command question asked : Find the name of each city and the number of benches in the city that has more than 3 branches, each with more than 1,000,000 in assets. I have attempted this using GROUP BY and HAVING, is this the correct method to go, unfortunately i cannot test as this is all theory with pen and paper

My attempt answer for this is :

```
SELECT branch_city, COUNT(branch_city)
FROM branch
WHERE assets > 1000000
GROUP BY branch_city
HAVING COUNT(branch_city) > 3
```

Comment: your probably going to get better responses if you present what you've tried, or at least in this case what you think, first.

Comment: If you have written some pseudo sql maybe add that to your question.

Comment: Updated all attempts in

Comment: I believe your SQL statement will return the result set you are looking for

Comment: After revisions I don't think this question deserves down votes or should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

**A candidate key is a column, or set of columns, in a table that can uniquely identify any database record without referring to any other data(no extra columns)**

account_number is the primary key in the account_branch table and therefore uniquely identifies a row in the table without any extraneous columns so yes this meets the criteria for a candidate key

**A superkey is a combination of columns that uniquely identifies any row within a relational database(may have extra columns not needed for uniqueness)**

Since Account_number is the primary key in the account_branch table and branch_name is a foreign key into the branch table Account_number + branch_name will uniquely identify a row in the account_branch relation so yes it is a superkey. Since Account_number + branch_name already identifies a unique row adding any other column from branch will still identify a unique record so Account_number + branch_name + assets is also a superkey.

```
SELECT branch_city, COUNT(branch_city)
FROM branch
WHERE assets > 1000000
GROUP BY branch_city
HAVING COUNT(branch_city) > 3
```

does return your desired result set:

```
SELECT branch_city
FROM branch
WHERE assets > 1000000
```

returns a result set from branch of all rows where assets are greater than 1000000

```
GROUP BY branch_city
```

Tells the database to group that result set by branch_city

adding the aggregate function

`COUNT(branch_city)`   /aggregate functions require a group by/

returns the number of rows, or occurrences, of each city in that result set

```
HAVING COUNT(branch_city) > 3
```

Then trims that result set down to only citys that occurred more than 3 times